# SQL: Combine two tables, into same columns, based on relation table

Tags: sql

Not being well versed in complex SQL, I am trying to figure out how I can write a query that will return (almost) the same columns from two tables, based on a "relationship" table.  I have tried using UNION, but the number of columns are different between the three tables.   I also tried IF...ELSE, but could not get that to function.  I have also looked at INCLUDE and EXCLUDE.

Here is my current query:

```
    SELECT 
    /* Relation Table */
    [data_Related_Asset].[ID_Related_Asset]
    ,[data_Related_Asset].[BIOMED_Tag]
    ,[data_Related_Asset].[Related_BIOMED_Tag]

    /* Lab Table */
    ,[data_Lab_Asset].[Room]
    ,[Lab_Area].[Work_Area]
    ,[data_Lab_Asset].[Pet_Name_Bench]
    ,[data_Lab_Asset].[BGL_ID]
    ,[data_Lab_Asset].[BIOMED_Tag] AS LAB_BIOMED
    ,[data_Lab_Asset].[Endpoint_Tag]
    ,[Lab_Class].[Class]
    ,[Lab_Class].[Subclass]
    ,[Lab_Class].[Subcategory]

    /* IT Table */
    ,[data_IT_Asset].[Room]
    ,[IT_Area].[Work_Area]
    ,[data_IT_Asset].[Bench_Instrument]
    ,[data_IT_Asset].[BIOMED_Tag] AS IT_BIOMED
    ,[data_IT_Asset].[Endpoint_Tag]
    ,[IT_Class].[Class]
    ,[IT_Class].[Subclass]
    ,[IT_Class].[Subcategory]
FROM [data_Related_Asset]
LEFT JOIN [data_Lab_Asset] ON [data_Lab_Asset].[BIOMED_Tag] = [data_Related_Asset].[Related_BIOMED_Tag]
LEFT JOIN [data_IT_Asset] ON [data_IT_Asset].[BIOMED_Tag] = [data_Related_Asset].[Related_BIOMED_Tag]
LEFT JOIN [tbl_Class] Lab_Class ON [Lab_Class].[ID_Class] = [data_Lab_Asset].[Class_ID]
LEFT JOIN [tbl_Class] IT_Class ON [IT_Class].[ID_Class] = [data_IT_Asset].[Class_ID]
LEFT JOIN [tbl_Work_Area] Lab_Area ON [Lab_Area].[ID_Work_Area] = [data_Lab_Asset].[Work_Area_ID]
LEFT JOIN [tbl_Work_Area] IT_Area ON [IT_Area].[ID_Work_Area] = [data_IT_Asset].[Work_Area_ID]
ORDER BY ID_Related_Asset
```

The query is being used in a custom app and is set up to search for an "ID" in the [data_Related_Asset].[BIOMED_Tag] column, and return all [Related_BIOMED_Tag] records.

When I run the above query I get all the results I need, but across a lot of columns.  If the item being return is in the LAB table, then the LAB_Asset columns are populated, but the IT_Asset columns are all NULL.  And if the item is in the IT table, the opposite is true - the LAB_Asset columns are all NULL and the IT_Asset columns are populated. For example, below you can see where rows 2 & 12 returned the IT_Asset information.

[image]

I'd like to be able to return everything in the same set of NINE columns to condense the viewed table. (Room, Work_Area, Bench, BGL_ID, BIOMED_Tag, Endpoint_Tag, Class, Subclass, Subcategory)  For example, below you can see where I moved the info from the IT_Asset table over to the first columns.

[image]

I'm sure I'm missing a simple solution/function here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since you're using `LEFT JOINs` it's only going to return non `NULL` if there's a match between the tables.  Otherwise you will return `NULL` in those columns for those rows.  This sounds like it's valid if you're joining to multiple tables and the results are showing as you expect.  If you're returning `NULLs` with your `LEFT JOINs` you wouldn't want to try to condense it down (say with `INNER JOINs`) because you'd lose data for non matches.

Comment: @WAMLeslie That's why I was trying to use an IF...ELSE statement to say IF [BIOMED_Tag] IS NOT NULL (on LAB_Table) THEN SELECT (columns) FROM [LAB_TABLE] ELSE SELECT (columns) FROM [IT_Table]  I expect to return NULL from either one table or the other - which is why I'd like to combine them into the same column set, so I don't see the NULL from the opposing table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION but you just have to ensure that you have the same columns in the same order in each statement being union'd.

So for missing columns just use nulls (or any suitable dummy data) e.g.

```
SELECT col1, col2, null, col4
from tableA
UNION
SELECT col1, null, col3, null
from tableB
```

Comment: While I did get this to work, it produces completely unexpected and unwanted results.  I don't think the JOIN(s) are working correctly.  I need to Join both the LAB_Table and IT_Table to the Related_Asset table via the BIOMED_Tag column on each table.  When using UNION, I get every record from all three tables, and everything is NULL where the Related_Asset table is returned.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the result you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry, should have though of that.  Added pics to show current and wanted results.